# rsync/diff like tool for MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb

I'm looking for a tool that will compare two mongo databases and let you sync specific documents one direction or another.

There's [the tool by 3T](http://3t.io/data-compare/), but IMO it's way overpriced for this kind of thing. I'd pay $60 tops.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Honestly, that is extremely cheap. Creating this kind of software requires extended knowledge and development time. If your use case is not worth a mere $199, it is probably not worth implementing it the first place. Maybe you should take a step back and find out why you have such a requirement and how to circumvent it.